# JPQL query- order by nested field

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Given a class OP

```
public class OP {
  String name;
  int rank;
}
```

and a class D

```
public class D {
  OP parameter; 
}
```

How should be the query written in JPQL that lists the instances of `D` class ordered by `rank` field of `OP` class. Instances having null references to `OP` objects must listed at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests I managed to get things work. This is how I have implemented it with Spring `Repository`:

```
@Repository
public interface DRepository extends CrudRepository<D, Long> {

    @Query("select d from D d left outer join d.parameter op order by op.rank desc")
    List<D> getDs();

}
```

Notice the `left outer join` to include `D` instances with null `parameter` field and the `desc` after the `order by` clause to force instances with null `OP` to the end of the list.